# Set Home button on each fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, swipe

My application uses fragments and swipes to navigate different pages. I want to have an image button on each fragment activity so that when pressed first activity should be available. How can I do this. I tried viewpager.setcurrentitem option but it is only available in main activity. and in fragment activity viewpager is not available. I know there is way to by using android default property of sethome button. But I want an image button in each fragment. 
This is my main activity

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
    ActionBar.TabListener {

SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Set up the action bar.
    final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the app.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(
            getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    // When swiping between different sections, select the corresponding
    // tab. We can also use ActionBar.Tab#select() to do this if we have
    // a reference to the Tab.
    mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                    actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
                }
            });


    Tab tab = actionBar.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.prf).setText(getString(R.string.title_section1)).setTabListener(this);
    actionBar.addTab(tab, true);

    tab = actionBar.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.pack).setText(getString(R.string.title_section2)).setIcon(R.drawable.pack).setTabListener(this);
    actionBar.addTab(tab);

    tab = actionBar.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.call).setText(getString(R.string.title_section3)).setTabListener(this);
    actionBar.addTab(tab);

    tab = actionBar.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.prom).setText(getString(R.string.title_section4)).setTabListener(this);
    actionBar.addTab(tab);

    tab = actionBar.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.infoin).setText(getString(R.string.title_section5)).setTabListener(this);
    actionBar.addTab(tab);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab,FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    // When the given tab is selected, switch to the corresponding page in
    // the ViewPager.
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab,FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab,FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
}

/**
 * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
 * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
 */
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
        case 0 :
            return new Home();
        case 1:
            return new info();
        case 2:
            return new Plan();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 3 total pages.
        return 3;
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems like your problem is that you don't know how Fragments can communicate with Activities and vice versa. 
Read this: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html then it'll be easy to add your home button to all of your fragments and use do viewPager.setCurrentItem() from your MainActivity.

Answer (score 0):

Use callback mechanism through **Interface** and send message back to **Activity** of what you want to do on click of **ImageButton**. Same mechanism is good for fragments communication with each other.